# Elasticsearch Geo_point query not returning results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to fetch all the documents within a radius of a particular location (lat,long).
**Here's the mapping with location as the geo_point**:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "color": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "createdTime": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "location": {
          "properties": {
            "lat": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "lon": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**And here's my query**

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "weather_agg": {
      "geo_distance": {
        "field": "location",
        "origin": "41.12,-100.77",
        "unit": "km",
        "distance_type": "plane",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": 0,
            "to": 100
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "timerange": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "createdTime": {
                "gte": "now-40h",
                "lte": "now"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "weather_stats": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "color"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting 0 hits for this. My question is whether there's something wrong with the mapping or the query ? We recently migrated to a newer cloud version and there's a possibility that something broke because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mapping `lat` and `long` as float you should [geo-point mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html)

Comment: I did have a template that maps that index to a mapping with location as geo_point. But there's a possibility that during migration it did not update mapping. What's my way to update the mapping for existing data?

Comment: That depends on how much data you have and whether you have data stored elsewhere. For example, we use ES as read storage in CQRS pattern so it's a matter of dropping the index and recreating it with correct mappings from write storage which. In case you don't have any additional storage there aren't any migration tools to my knowledge. But you can write a script that creates a field with correct mapping, updates documents, and drops a field with incorrect mapping.